# Nested list with number labels

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

I have a nested list, and therefore I want the label to be nested too.

This is my code:

```
<!-- For first list -->
<xsl:template name="list1-label">
    <xsl:number format="1."/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- The nestled list -->
<xsl:template name="list2-label">
    <xsl:number format="1.1."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The first number in the last template (**1**.1.) I want to be relative to the parent item, in this case; "3".

Here is the xml structure:

```
<list1>
  <item>Test</item>
  <item>Test</item>
  <list2>
    <item>Test</item>
    <item>Test</item>
  </list2>
  <item>Test</item>
</list1>
```

Here is the output:

```
1. Test
2. Test
    2.1. Test
    2.2. Test
3. Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wanted output can be obtained (for example) applying the advanced attributes **@from** and **@count** of `xsl:number`. Here a working example from which you should get started:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="list1/item">  
        <xsl:number level="any" from="list1" count="list1/item"/>
        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list1/list2/item">
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number level="any" from="list1" count="list1/item"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number level="any" from="list2" count="list2/item"/>
        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you want to simplify the match patterns:

```
<xsl:template match="list1">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list1/item">  
    <xsl:number level="any" from="list1" count="list1/item"/>
    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list2/item">
    <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number level="any" from="list1" count="list1/item"/>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number level="any" from="list2" count="list2/item"/>
    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This latest example will correctly drive you to further nesting levels as with a **list3**.

Answer (score 1):

For the nested list you should probably be using `level="multiple" count="X|Y"` but I can't be more precise than that without knowing (a) what your XML source looks like, and (b) what the context item is at the point where your named templates are called.

Answer (score 1):

This new transform is generalized to handle a variable number of lists.

Input sample:

```
<list1>
  <item>Test</item>
  <item>Test</item>
  <list2>
        <item>Test</item>
        <list3>
            <item>Test</item>
            <item>Test</item>
        </list3>
        <item>Test</item>
        <list3>
            <item>Test</item>
        </list3>
        <item>Test</item>
  </list2>
  <item>Test</item>
</list1>
```

transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'list')]">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="tab" select="true()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:param name="lvl" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
        <xsl:param name="tab" select="false()"/>

        <!-- insert entry point tab -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()[$tab and $lvl > 1]" mode="tab">
            <xsl:with-param name="lvl" select="$lvl - 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <!-- recurse levels -->
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="name(ancestor::*[$lvl])"/>
        <xsl:number level="any" from="*[name()=$name]" 
            count="*[name()=$name]/item"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::item[$lvl > 1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="lvl" select="$lvl - 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <!-- print value -->
        <xsl:if test="$lvl = 1">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="tab">
        <xsl:param name="lvl"/>
        <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::text()[$lvl>1]" mode="tab">
            <xsl:with-param name="lvl" select="$lvl - 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
1. Test
2. Test
    2.1. Test
        2.1.1. Test
        2.1.2. Test
    2.2. Test
        2.2.1. Test
    2.3. Test
3. Test
```